# What’s the difference between SMTP clients and servers for protocol flows in C++

Tags: sockets, server, smtp, network-programming

I do some research on SMTP which is Simple Mail Transfer Protocol on mechanisms of sending emails over the Internet. From RFCs I know there is a communication progress under the client/server mode. For example, the client will initiate a session with a HELO or EHLO command to the server, and if the server is OK to accept this request, it will reply with a 250 message together with a series of available commands and status code of the server. Then you can go on the protocol procedure to until you send your mail, this is a typical network protocol process to implement the task.

I want to know what happens after the client finish its work communicating with the local server, the mail sent to the server should be carried on to another server on the Internet, and it would be relayed several times before it reaches its final destination. What’s the progress between the email servers? How do servers implement the SMTP to realize the relaying process?

I have done some work on documentations and references on SMTP servers, while there not many, so I write this question. This is a general question, any advices or example codes would be appreciated.
Thanks.

I wrote a SMTP client, here is my code in C++, it can work to send mails, what's the SMTP server side code typically of the protocol flow, to listen and accept mails?

```
//Send EHLO to servers
std::string command = "EHLO \r\n";
Write(command.c_str(), command.length());
memset(buffer, 0, 1024);
Read(buffer, 1023);
if (strncmp(buffer, "250", 3) != 0) // ehlo failed
{
    lastErrorMsg = buffer;
    return -1;
}
```

Comment: It is not clear to me what you are asking. And from the title it does not look like its not about programming at all (i.e. off-topic here) - but about an understanding what the role SMTP plays in mail delivery and what not. In general: each client (i.e. MUA, MTA) knows only if the mail got successfully delivered to the next hop and has no knowledge about further delivery steps. So if the delivery fails somewhere at the path the submitting MTA is supposed to send a DSN (delivery status notification) back to the original sender as a new mail.

Comment: Mail servers also talk SMTP between each others: a mail server may be the server when it accepts an email from e.g., your email client, and it maybe the client when it passes that email to another SMTP server. Usually the email is first placed in a  queue and even written to disk, to make sure not to lose it in case of a crash. There is also retry logic, in case the next server is temporarily unavailable. Check the code of some open source MTA like Postfix, KumoMta, or Apache James. That said, your question is a bit too broad for stackoverflow, see [ask].

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: Thank you for your advices, the open source MTA are helpful.

Answer (score 0):

On the modern Internet, mail is sent from the origin directly to the destination using SMTP - it's never relayed.

my computer -> my server -> your server -> your computer

When I (me@gmail.com using Outlook Express on my computer) send an email to you (you@hotmail.com, using Thunderbird on your computer), Outlook Express connects to Gmail's SMTP server and sends the mail. Then its job is done.

Note that if I use Gmail's web page or Gmail's app to send an email, it uses some secret Google protocol instead of using SMTP. That's why I'm talking about Outlook Express.

When Gmail's server feels like it, it connects to Hotmail's SMTP server and sends the mail. Then its job is done. Most real SMTP servers try to send emails straight away - there's no point in waiting - but waiting is allowed.

Once Hotmail's server gets the email, it puts the email in your mailbox on Hotmail's server.

If the sender and recipient are the same server (e.g. me@gmail.com to you@gmail.com) the SMTP server can put the message directly in your mailbox.

Once you eventually open Thunderbird on your computer, it connects to Hotmail's POP3 or IMAP server and downloads the new emails from the mailbox.

---

What *is* a mailbox? SMTP doesn't care - that's your job. One easy way to make a mailbox is to just make a folder and put a new file in the folder every time an email is received.

---

To prevent spam, most SMTP servers only accept two kinds of mail: mail that comes from a user of that server, if they're logged in, and mail that's going to a user of that server, if it comes from the right address.

- If I connect to gmail.com's SMTP server and tell it to send an email from me@gmail.com to you@hotmail.com, it's going to tell me to go away unless I log in.
- If I connect to gmail.com's SMTP server and tell it to send an email from me@outlook.com to you@hotmail.com, it's going to tell me to go away.
- If I connect to gmail.com's SMTP server and tell it to send an email from me@hotmail.com to you@gmail.com, it's going to accept the email, but it's going to check that I'm an authorized SMTP server for hotmail.com.

If you're making a toy server, you don't need to bother about any of this. Just know that you probably won't be able to send emails to big places like gmail because they'll think you're a spammer. You can still make a server that lets you send emails to addresses on that server.

---

How do you write an SMTP server? You just follow the RFC, actually - it's not too difficult. Please note that `Read(buffer, 1023);` doesn't always read a whole command line. It reads "some data", which could be a line, or several lines (if the client uses pipelining) or just one packet of a line. You're supposed to keep reading over and over until you get the whole amount of data you want.

As long as your server supports the basic SMTP commands, you should be able to set it up in Thunderbird and send it an email to it. I recommend that you make the server save the commands it gets in a file, or print them on the screen, so you can see what is happening when it doesn't work.

Alternatively if you have a domain name (Internet address like zhiweihe.com) and your server is on the internet, you should be able to send an email to an address on your server, *from* a place like Gmail (there are no spam checks in this direction) and you can feel important as one of Google's servers will connect to your server to deliver the email. You will need to create an MX record in DNS.

If you programmed your server to save the incoming emails into a folder, you can look in the folder and see the new email. If you want to see them in Thunderbird instead of in a folder, you'll have to implement a POP3 server as well. Most email programs can use either POP3 or IMAP to download emails - I don't recommend starting with IMAP because it's a lot more complicated.